# JAVA: How to make java EXE run on different PCs

Tags: exe, launch4j

I created mini project on Java. Using Eclipse I converted my project to .JAR and later .JAR to .EXE using launch4j 3.12 . On **my PC** exe work correct. But if I share my file to my friends which, File give a error:

> "A JNI Error has occurred, please check your installation and try again".

And in launch4j's console print:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Game has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0".

But I specified the path to jre. How can I fix this problem and launch my Java Project on my friends PCs?  My launch4j config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <launch4jConfig>
    <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
    <headerType>gui</headerType>
    <jar>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\JavaProject\JARFile.jar</jar>
    <outfile>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\JavaProject\game.exe</outfile>
    <errTitle></errTitle>
    <cmdLine></cmdLine>
    <chdir>.</chdir>
    <priority>normal</priority>
    <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
    <supportUrl></supportUrl>
    <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
    <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
    <manifest></manifest>
    <icon></icon>
    <jre>
        <path>javafiles/jre</path>
        <bundledJre64Bit>true</bundledJre64Bit>
        <bundledJreAsFallback>true</bundledJreAsFallback>
        <minVersion>1</minVersion>
        <maxVersion></maxVersion>
        <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
        <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
   </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Comment: the problem is that your program requires at least java version 59 (java 15) while on your friends computers only java version 52 (java 8) is installed.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your program requires at least java version 59 (java 15) while on your friends computers only java version 52 (java 8) is installed.

so there are two solutions:

- compile with older java version if you do not need newer language features
- upgrade to java 15 jre/jdk on your friends computers that want to run your program